# Strange output from nunique after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am intrigued by the behavior of the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','A','B','B','B'],
                   'Date':['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df['Data_Points'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Date'].transform('nunique')
print(df)
```

Which outputs:

```
  Name       Date                   Data_Points
0    A 2020-01-01 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002
1    A 2020-01-02 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002
2    B 2020-01-01 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003
3    B 2020-01-02 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003
4    B 2020-01-03 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003
```

The question comes as to why am I getting a datetime value after using `transform('nunique')` if the documentation for [pandas.Series.nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html#pandas.Series.nunique) clear states:

> Return number of unique elements in the object.
>
> > Returns:
> > int

And [pandas.DataFrame.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) does not mention anything about retaining the dtype of the aggregated column, only:

> Call func on self producing a DataFrame with transformed values.
> Produced DataFrame will have same axis length as self.

So therefore, when combining both functions, why am I getting a `datetime` instead of the `int` as `nunique()` says? Does the aggregated `dtype` have precedence over the function being passed in the `transform()` method when defining the `dtype` of the transformed column? Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, it is because the transformed result is inserted back as a datetime (the original) type. Add `astype(int)` solves it:

```
df.groupby('Name')["Date"].transform("nunique").astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0    2
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is bug, possible solution:

```
df['Data_Points'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Date'].transform(pd.Series.nunique)
print(df)
  Name       Date  Data_Points
0    A 2020-01-01            2
1    A 2020-01-02            2
2    B 2020-01-01            3
3    B 2020-01-02            3
4    B 2020-01-03            3
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea, I've created a new dataframe because `df.groupby(['Customer Name','Time Periods'])['Sales_Date'].nunique()` does return `int` too and then I'm joining back. +1 for quick answer and solution