# Moving dummy counts from each row to a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, rows

I am trying this problem but not getting the right solution.

So, I have a data which has City and Months mapped to them

| City | Month |
| --- | --- |
| A | M1 |
| A | M2 |
| B | M3 |
| B | M4 |
| C | M5 |
| C | M8 |

I have created dummy variables and have marked them as binary in this manner

| City | M1 | M2 | M3 | M4 | M5 | M8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Now, the main problem is, I want to mark each location to a month in a single row, like this

| City | M1 | M2 | M3 | M4 | M5 | M8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Can anyone suggest how to move from table 2 to table 3 structure? I do not want to hard code them as different locations might get assigned random months in subsequent data. Getting dummy variables in easy but how do I get to last format? any useful functions existing in python for this?

Comment: What data type are you using for the above tables? Can you share please your code?

Comment: I think pivot_table with `len` not return indicator columns, but counts. Only if no duplicates get `0,1`, else 0,1,2,... counts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved by using `pivot_table()`. The trick here is to use `len` as aggfunc.

```
df.pivot_table(index='City',columns='Month',aggfunc=len,fill_value=0).clip(1,0)
```

Outputs:

```
Month  M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M8
City                         
A       1   1   0   0   0   0
B       0   0   1   1   0   0
C       0   0   0   0   1   1
```

Comment: answer not return indicator column, but counts.

Comment: So perhaps adding (where >= 1,1,0)?

Comment: ya, then it is better.

Comment: but first should convert answer to wiki, because duplicate working well.

Comment: I know hehe I have been following your answers for 2 years :) Best quality.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791549/combine-rows-in-dataframe-column-based-on-condition/65791597#comment116322984_65791597
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650860/strange-output-from-nunique-after-groupby/62650880#comment110793369_62650880

Comment: applymap, ouch, it is not vectorized, need `clip`